# How to pass variable from controller to model - Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am currently trying to pass a variable from the controller to my model. From a previous view  I was passed $id in a button.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" type="button" href="index.php?r=recipient/index&id=<?php echo $data->id; ?>">Manage</a>
```

From there, I have accessed $id inside my controller and used it. However, now I am creating a function in the model that needs to use that $id. I can't pass it in as a argument because it is the function beforeSave (which updates my database before I've saved a new entry) 
This looks like this in the model Recipient.php

```
// before you save the function here are the things you should do
public function beforeSave()
{
    if($this->isNewRecord)
    {

        // updates the list_id of the individual with the selected ListId

        $this->list_id = Recipient::model()->getListId;


    }
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Finally, I am trying to create the function getListId in the same model.

```
public function getListId()
{
    // my code here 
}
```

Is there a simple way to pass a variable from the controller to the model to use? Or, is there a way for a function in the model to access a variable passed to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your model and set that property in your controller.

```
class Model
{
    public $var;
    ... more code ...
}

actionIndex($idList)
{
    $model = Model::model()->find(...);
    $model->var = $idList;
    ... more code ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to simply call the entire model? As opposed to using the method find()? I'm not entirely sure what I should be searching for when really I just want to pass in the variable into the model. 

As well, when I am trying to reaccess the variable $var back in the model in a function - I find that it is not showing up anything. Can I not set global variables like this?

Comment: I am not quite sure what this all is about. It seems to me that you are probably using the wrong approach to achieve something. It just looks wrong to me...
Can you explain what exactly you want to build? What is this `listId`? Is it dynamic? Can't you save it with the model? Or is it a realtion to another db table?

Comment: So, the listID is a foreign key that I am trying to save inside of the   Recipient Model. I have a bunch of different lists and each of the recipients are linked to one of the lists. When I click to "Manage a list" I go to the recipient index where I can view the recipients of that list. The id is passed from the view into the controller

Comment: From here the ultimate goal is that whenever  I create a new recipient, I would like it to update the recipient list_id with the id of the list that they previously clicked on.

Comment: I'm trying to do essentially what you did above, where I can then store the variable of the id somewhere that is NOT a view so that  I can access it when I am creating a new recipient.

Comment: So you want to be able to change the listId of a single recipient and store that change in DB? If so you should have a field in your recipient table `list_id`. You need to remove the list_id property from the model for this to work. You can still set the list_id like above. Since this is active record, it would be saved automatically with the model.

Comment: You are saying I should get rid of the public $var part? And then I will be able to call that $var inside of a model function like beforeSave()?

Comment: If you have a field in your db table recipient, then yes, because it would be accessed directly. When you don't take it out, it would be used over the db field and not saved if I recall correctly.